# Slow DNS resolution when accessing the public network in centos7

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7

I've tried 3 sets of DNS servers. When my server accesses the public network, DNS parsing takes 5 seconds before success.

Questions:
How to locate and solve the problem of slow DNS resolution when accessing the public network?

Answer (score 0):

Use tools like `mtr` to mesure packet loss and latancy to your DNS servers.
If there is no packet loss and the latency is good (below 10ms is ok for local DNS server) try to trace the problem by using `dig +trace google.com @YOUR_DNS_SERVER` and observe the response time on each line.